# Starting out: Heroku with Ruby (Windows 7)

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm following this tutorial on Heroku with Ruby on Windows 7. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby#run-the-app-locally

I have close to 0 prior programming knowledge.

Everything works fine up until step #9, "***Run the app locally***", where I run into the following problem:

I have installed Postgres, but when I run `config\database.yml`

I get an error saying

> "Can not open file ' C: ... database.yml ' as archive".

I am not able to find a solution to this.

I have:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled Postgres
- Run tutorial from start

I'm running Ruby version 2.3.3, Gemfile 2.3.1.

---

Edit
The steps taken:

```
cd jruby-getting-started

heroku create

git push heroku master

heroku ps:scale web=1

heroku open

heroku logs --tail
```

control + c stop streaming logs

```
type Procfile

heroku ps

heroku ps:scale web=0

heroku ps:scale web=1

jruby -S bundle install --binstubs
```

output: "Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1"

```
config\database.yml
```

opens pgAdmin in browser

```
jruby -S bin\rake db:create db:migrate

heroku local web -f Procfile.windows
```

Looks like an error:

> [OKAY] Loaded ENV .env File as KEY=VALUE Format 22:43:25 web.1   | 
>   WARNING: An illegal reflect
>
> 22:43:25 web.1   |  WARNING: Illegal reflective er$ReflectiveAccess to
>   method sun.nio.ch.SelChI 22:43:25 web.1   |  WARNING: Please consider
>   re f jnr.posix.JavaLibCHelper$ReflectiveAccess 22:43:25 web.1   | 
>   WARNING: Use --illegal-acce ther illegal reflective access operations
>   22:43:25 web.1   |  WARNING: All illegal access uture release 22:43:25
>   web.1   |  SyntaxError: bin\puma:1: sy 22:43:25 web.1   | 
>   JRuby::Commands.bin\puma [DONE] Killing all processes with signal 
>   SIGIN 22:43:25 web.1   Exited with exit code null

Next instruction: "Open http://localhost:5000 with your web browser. You should see your app running locally."
I try to open in browser --> Error: Unable to open page

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Please post the exact command to start the app locally and copy and paste the full error messages including the whole stack trace into your question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to unzip something that you downloaded

Comment: Articles on remote sites change and links can die; please post the steps to reproduce your configuration directly in your question. It is not sufficient to link to the remote site.

Comment: Thx to all for input.

7-zip was default for yml files - I changed the default to pgAdmin 4. Able to continue / no error at this stage.

I post all my steps in a comment below as it has too many char to fit in this post. Hopefully that makes it more clear as why I run into the next problem.

Answer (score -1):

Did you download this codebase? where is it located? Can you open files in the codebase (like Gemfile)? You may need to unzip the codebase still as someone commented.

`config\database.yml` is a config file you are going to edit. You don't typically "run" it but open it with a text editor.

Comment: I have the codebase downloaded on my computer. I can open the files. I do not see any zipped files there.

Thanks @C-RAD. I did not understand I was supposed to open it with a text editor. I did so and found what to edit.

New problem. Added it in an edit above in OT.

Comment: Nice! Okay so a couple of things here:

1. That error is probably causing your web server to not start. `Exited with exit code null` means the process is dead. I'm not certain on what it's trying to tell you but if I were to guess your environment is not configured correctly. It looks like JRuby can't run Puma correctly (JRuby is just ruby being run by Java, and Puma is just the webserver [program] that will run your rails app). You might try googling parts of that error and check to see if your java version can be updated.

Comment: 2. I don't think many people use PgAdmin for editing source code files. You probably want to check out another editor like VScode, which a lot of people use and really love.

Comment: 3. Regarding your setup, Heroku is a cloud platform which is useful for deploying rails apps to the web, I'm not sure if it's where I would start if I were just trying to learn rails. Also, ruby/rails, for a long time has been notoriously hard to install on windows, and I don't know of a lot of people who develop rails on windows and you're probably going to run into more issues since windows 7 has reached end of life and is no longer supported. Additionally, using JRuby as opposed to a more commonly used ruby may cause more difficulties

Comment: And I'm sure I've angered enough people with my opinions already, but for you I would recommend, either A. installing linux on pc and running ruby there, B. Installing a virutalbox VM on your windows pc, and running ruby in the vm, or C. use the instructions from the first chapter of the Hartl tutorial here: (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#sec-up_and_running) to get up and running on cloud9. If you don't want to buy that whole book (and it is a great rails tutorial) then you can continue with other coding tutorials once you have a reliable development setup.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, @C-RAD. Sounds like I chose not the best starting project for my setup. I'll follow your suggestion and start with something easier for my current knowledge and that works more smoothly with win 7. Appreciate the help.

Comment: This is not an answer; it's a series of questions that should be posed as comments to the question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: I can't comment until my rep is over 50.

Comment: And? Answers are for **answers**, not comments or questions. You'll never get to 50 rep by posting non-answers as answers.

Comment: And I had no other way to help the OP, so I asked them to clarify their question the only way I could, and together we solved the problem so they could move forward. If you’re actually interested in helping people and not just trolling me then maybe you should parse out the solution that we came to as a concise answer for future visitors.

Comment: So you're saying that not only was it not an answer, but now that you believe you've come to an answer you won't even update your answer to be a real answer, because the quality of the content on this site isn't important and you don't think it's important to leave quality answers? I suggest reading the help center topics on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to understand why this is at -1 and why it should be removed.